# Dividing words in an equation

Tags: equations

I'm writing a report in LaTeX, and I have a lot of formulas written in words, and they are too long. So I would like to write the formula in such way that for example the word *Delež časovnih razmejitev v financiranju* is written in vertical order, so *Delež časovnih razmejitev* in the first line and then below the word *v financiranju*. The code I have is below.

I tried `\\`, and the `multiline` enviroment, but it is not working. So can anybody tell me how I can do this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,openany]{report}
\usepackage{ashmatt}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\mbox{Delež časovnih razmejitev v financiranju}=\frac{\mbox{vsota dolgoročnih rezervacij  in kratkoročnih pasivnih časovnih razmejitev }}{\mbox{obveznosti do virov sredstev}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You could use a `\parbox`...

Comment: I thought the point of symbolic logic was to avoid words (The sum of the squares of the legs of a right triangle equals the square of the hypotenuse).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might consider using `\parbox`es:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,openany]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\eqtext}[2][.4\textwidth]{\parbox{#1}{\centering #2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \eqtext{Delež časovnih razmejitev v financiranju}
  = \frac{\eqtext{vsota dolgoročnih rezervacij  in kratkoročnih
  pasivnih časovnih razmejitev}}{\eqtext{obveznosti do virov sredstev}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Here I have essentially used

```
 \parbox{.4\textwidth}{\centering ...text...}
```

but packaged this into a macro `\eqtext` so you can write

```
 \eqtext{...text...}
```

or

```
\eqtext[0.7\textwidth]{...text...}
```

if a different width is desired.

Answer (score 5):

Using a `tabular` you need no guesswork:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,openany]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\splittext}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  #1
  \end{tabular}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\splittext{Delež časovnih razmejitev \\ v financiranju}=
\frac{
  \splittext{vsota dolgoročnih rezervacij \\ in kratkoročnih pasivnih \\ časovnih razmejitev}
}{
  \splittext{obveznosti do virov sredstev}
}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It works with `multline*`, but you have to indicate where you want line breaks:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,openany]{report}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{mathtools} % extends amsmath
  \begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
\text{Delež časovnih razmejitev v financiranju}=\\
\frac{\text{vsota dolgoročnih rezervacij in kratkoročnih pasivnih časovnih razmejitev }}{\text{obveznosti do virov sredstev}}
 \end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I could do it this way. 
But how can I divide only this word 
\text{Delež časovnih razmejitev v financiranju}=

Comment: @M.xx: Do you mean you want the equation on a single line, dividing only the text before `=`?